# React Sortable Tree: Expand each node by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my react project, I am using [react-sortable-tree](https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree) .

However, I miss the option to expand all the nodes by default.

Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Edit:

expand = {true}

toggleExpandedForAll={true}

is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer was not to add these options to the component as props but rather to add them to the datatree that you want to parse it ...

```
    const flatData = dataTreeFrom2.map((node) => ({
        ...node,
        title: node.limitGroupName,
        expanded:true,
        className: ""
    }));
```